SMS to Email in Azure/365/Exchange
General question and wondering. Does anyone how (if it can be done) to setup an SMS to email service in Azure, 365 and or Exchange?
I'm trying (in the most cost effective way as there are likely to be fewer than 10 SMS messages received per week) to setup and SMS to Email process.  An text comes in and the content of the message is simply dropped directly into an email and forwarded on.
No complexities, not logic...just pass through.
Any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Yes, it is possible to set up an SMS to email service in Microsoft 365 or Office 365. One option is to use a connector to send emails using Microsoft 365 or Office 365 SMTP relay. Another option is to use Azure Communication Services to receive incoming msgs and configure Azure Event Grid to forward them to an email addr. However, there may be limitations & costs associated with these options. For eg- SMTP relay option requires static unshared IP addresses and may have reasonable limits for sending. Additionally, Azure Communication Services may charge for messages sent to landline numbers.

References:

How to set up a multifunction device or application to send emails using Microsoft 365 or Office 365
SMS FAQ

